# Create a unique name by combining the values in the first and last names array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two arrays, and I want to create a name by combining these two arrays.
However, there should be no duplicates.

Can I return a random name as if it were random, in addition to the recursive way of looking up an array of name result values?

The easiest way to do this is to store the randomly generated names in a list, and look up the list each time you create a new name like below.

```py
import random
first_name = ['tony', 'adam', 'agustin', 'branden','stan']
last_name = ['smith', 'stark',  'wlliams']

full_name_dup_list = []

def generate_full_name():
    full_name =random.choice(first_name) +" "+ random.choice(last_name)
    if full_name in full_name_dup_list:
        generate_full_name()
    else:
        full_name_dup_list.append(full_name)
        print(full_name)



generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()

result: 
tony stark                                                                                                                                                                                             
tony wlliams                                                                                                                                                                                           
branden stark                                                                                                                                                                                          
branden smith                                                                                                                                                                                          
adam stark                                                                                                                                                                                             
agustin stark                                                                                                                                                                                          
agustin smith                                                                                                                                                                                          
stan smith
```

Every result are non-duplicated full_name.

However, I don't want to use a method that checks for arrays that have already been created. 
Because the size of the array grows and the number of returned values increases, the function may continue to perform recursively when it is unfortunate.

Here another plan: 
Like 2-depth for statement

```py
import random
first_name = ['tony', 'adam', 'agustin', 'branden','stan']
last_name = ['smith', 'stark',  'wlliams']

class Index():
    idx_first = 0 
    idx_last = 0 


def generate_full_name():
    full_name=first_name[Index.idx_first] + " " + last_name[Index.idx_last]
    print(full_name)
    Index.idx_last=Index.idx_last+1
    if Index.idx_last== len(last_name)-1:
        Index.idx_first=Index.idx_first+1
        Index.idx_last=0

generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()
generate_full_name()

result: 
tony smith                                                                                                                                                                                             
tony stark                                                                                                                                                                                             
adam smith                                                                                                                                                                                             
adam stark                                                                                                                                                                                             
agustin smith                                                                                                                                                                                          
agustin stark                                                                                                                                                                                          
branden smith
```

But it seems like non-random.

Question: Could I create a function that outputs a fullname list like random instead of checking for an existing array of full names?

Answer (score 1):

One option is having set of duplicates, and using generators:

```
import random

first_name = ['tony', 'adam', 'agustin', 'branden','stan']
last_name = ['smith', 'stark',  'wlliams']

def generate_random_names(first, last):
    duplicates = set()
    while True:
        f = random.choice(first)
        l = random.choice(last)
        if (f, l) in duplicates:
            continue
        duplicates.add((f, l))
        yield f, l

for i, (f, l) in zip(range(1, 11), generate_random_names(first_name, last_name)):
    print('{}. {} {}'.format(i, f, l))
```

Prints:

```
1. stan wlliams
2. adam wlliams
3. tony wlliams
4. adam stark
5. tony stark
6. branden wlliams
7. stan stark
8. agustin smith
9. branden stark
10. agustin wlliams
```

Another version is using `itertools.product` and `random.sample`:

```
import random
from itertools import product

first_name = ['tony', 'adam', 'agustin', 'branden','stan']
last_name = ['smith', 'stark',  'wlliams']

print(random.sample([*product(first_name, last_name)], 10))
```

Prints:

```
[('stan', 'wlliams'), ('tony', 'stark'), ('agustin', 'smith'), ('agustin', 'wlliams'), ('tony', 'smith'), ('tony', 'wlliams'), ('stan', 'stark'), ('branden', 'stark'), ('stan', 'smith'), ('branden', 'wlliams')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You know how many names are possible -- just `len(first) * len(last)`. You can generate a random sample in this range and then do a little math to match the combinations to the generated number(s). For a given integer in the range the mapping would be:

```
f = first_name[s // len(last_name)]
l = last_name[s % len(last_name)]
```

With than you can use `random.sample` and then build the names:

```
import random

first_name = ['tony', 'adam', 'agustin', 'branden','stan']
last_name = ['smith', 'stark',  'wlliams']

total = len(first_name) * len(last_name)
sam = random.sample(range(total), 10)

[f'{first_name[s // len(last_name)]} {last_name[s % len(last_name)]}' for s in sam]
```

**Result:**

```
['adam stark',
 'branden smith',
 'agustin smith',
 'stan wlliams',
 'tony smith',
 'stan stark',
 'branden wlliams',
 'agustin stark',
 'stan smith',
 'tony wlliams']
```

`random.sample()` will throw an error if you try to take more than the total number which is probably what you want since then you would need dupes.

Comment: I like using the `sample()` with indexes! I used `product()` for that but this seems clever/more efficient. Upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do this is with a hash table: each string is indexed with an easily recovered hash code.  Python will do this for you quite easily: put the names into a `set`, and then just check to see whether the new name you generate is already in the set.  Make new choices until you get one you haven't yet used.

```
full_name_dup_set = set()

def generate_full_name():

    full_name = random.choice(first_name) + " " + \
                random.choice(last_name)

    while full_name in full_name_dup_set:
        full_name = random.choice(first_name) + " " + \
                    random.choice(last_name)

    full_name_dup_set.add(full_name)
    print(full_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ALL combination of first and last name, you can use below.  Product is a cartesian product in sql.

```
from itertools import product
[" ".join(list(name)) for name in product(first_name, last_name)]
```

Result:

```
['tony smith',
 'tony stark',
 'tony wlliams',
 'adam smith',
 'adam stark',
 'adam wlliams',
 'agustin smith',
 'agustin stark',
 'agustin wlliams',
 'branden smith',
 'branden stark',
 'branden wlliams',
 'stan smith',
 'stan stark',
 'stan wlliams']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will produce random combinations without pre-generating all first-last name pairs and without iterative trial and error loops:

```
def generateNames():
    names  = dict()
    allLast = set(range(len(last_name)))
    while True:
        if not names: names = { iFirst:[] for iFirst in range(len(first_name)) }
        iFirst,usedLast = random.choice(list(names.items()))
        remainingLast  = list(allLast.difference(usedLast))
        iLast = random.choice(remainingLast)
        usedLast.append(iLast)
        if not allLast.difference(usedLast): del names[iFirst]
        yield first_name[iFirst]+" "+last_name[iLast]        
randomName = generateNames()

for _ in range(10): 
   print(next(randomName))

tony wlliams
agustin smith
stan stark
stan wlliams
tony smith
branden wlliams
tony stark
branden stark
agustin stark
stan smith
```

The idea is to keep track of the last names used for each first name. It randomly select a first name, then randomly select a last name out of the remaining ones for that first name.  This way, you always get a unique combination on the first try (as opposed to trial/error approaches that will statistically take more and more time as you get more names).

When all the last names of a first name are used, that first name is eliminated and will not be eligible for subsequent random choices.

The solution is implemented as an infinite iterator that will cycle back to the beginning if you ever reach the end of combinations.  This allows you to call next(randomName) anywhere in your logic and as many times as needed.

An alternate approach that uses a bit more memory but still avoids generating a bazillion strings would be to generate a randomized list of composite indexes and build the full name from the index when needed.  This will take up a lot less space than pre-assembling all the full names (but still one integer per combination):

```
from collections import deque

firstCount = len(first_name)
lastCount  = len(last_name)
fullCount  = firstCount*lastCount
names = deque(random.sample(range(fullCount),fullCount))

def randomFullName():
    names.rotate(1)
    i = names[0]
    iFirst = i // lastCount
    iLast  = i % lastCount
    return first_name[iFirst] + " " + last_name[iLast]

for _ in range(10): 
    print(randomFullName())
```

Rotating on a deque allows the function to continue generating names even if you call it more times than there are combinations.   This approach does not require you to know in advance how many names you will need to generate.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

    from random import sample

    first_names = ["Bob", "Tom", "Jay"]
    last_names = ["Jones", "Watson", "Smith"]

    all_possible_names = [f"{first} {last}" for first in first_names for last in last_names]

    print(sample(all_possible_names, k=4))

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

1. Generate a list of all possible names.
2. Take a random sample (In my case, I cannot take more than 9 samples)